# How to search for text in line using python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I want to search for some text in a line.  As an example, text is:

```
{'id: 'id-::blabla1::blabal2-A'}
```

or

```
{'id: 'id-::blabla3::blabal4-B'}
```

or

```
{'id: 'id-::blabla5::blabal6-c'}
```

I want to find this text: `A` or `B` or `C`.  How do I build a regular expression in python to do this?

Comment: *to find this text, A or B or C* - in any position OR at the end?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean a dictionary although you miss a ' in both cases.

I guess something like this is what you're looking for:

```
import re
dict = {'id': 'id-::blabla1::blabal2-A'}
test = re.sub(r'.+?::.+?::.+?-(\w)',r'\1',dict['id'])
```

regex could be simplified but this is all I can do you for based on this info

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this one :

```
{'id: 'id-(?::.*?){2}-([a-zA-Z])'}
```

see : https://regex101.com/r/XnlUTi/2

```
([a-zA-Z])
```

This will be the group match who return A or B or c

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

content = "{'id: 'id-::blabla1::blabal2-A'}"
pattern = re.compile('{\'id: \'id-::blabla.*?::blabal.*?-(.*?)\'}', re.S)
print re.findall(pattern, content)
```

`.*?` represents anything, `(.*?)` represents things that you want.

`re.findall(pattern, content)` will return a list that meet the regular expression.